# Crystal reports if statement trying to include and exclude on the same field

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports, subreport

In a sub report I'm trying to return a "Yes" or True to main report if both conditions in if statement exist.  The issue is that the report evaluates each row and I want it to look for both conditions in all rows as a group.

What I've tried:

```
shared stringvar PRODCAT:= if ({OEORDLIN_SQL.prod_cat} in ["TRD","TSI"])
and 
not({OEORDLIN_SQL.prod_cat} in ["TRD","TSI"]) then "Yes" else "No"
```

I added formulas for both conditions A and B and used them in a formula, but I'm getting the same results.  It will only evaluate each row:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared stringvar PRODCAT:= if {@a} = "Yes" and {@b} = "Yes" then "Yes" else "No"
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble understanding the logic you're after from your code. In simplest terms, you want the subreport to return True if both "TRD" and "TSI" appear in it?

Comment: Why don't you use a `sql expression` in the mail report?  It would be much easier.

Comment: Another problem: how can `{OEORDLIN_SQL.prod_cat} be IN and NOT IN TRD and TSI at the same time?

Comment: Sub report is passing fine. Problem is formula is running on each item on the report. So if there are 3 items I get three results. I need the formula to run against all items as a whole and return one result.

Answer (score 0):

Create two `sql expression` fields:

```
// {%TRD}
(
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM   OEORDLIN_SQL a
  WHERE  order_id = order.order_id
  AND    prod_cat='TRD'
  GROUP BY order_id
)

// {%TSI}
(
  SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM   OEORDLIN_SQL b
  WHERE  order_id = order.order_id
  AND    prod_cat='TSI'
  GROUP BY order_id
)
```

Use as needed:

```
// {@do something}
If {%TSD}>0 AND {%TSI>0 Then
  ...
Else
 ...
```

Comment: Ryan,  The data is coming from items on an order.  So on the order I need to find if I have items with both a prodcat of "TRD"or "TSI" and where items don't have these prodcat. example - item 1 prodcat = "TRD" item 2 proccat = "ABC".

Comment: Craig - each item is returned as a row.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn't realized your problem was inserting a summary field.

Create two numeric functions, isInPRODCAT and isNotInPRODCAT.  Insert them into the detail section of your report.

```
isInPRODCAT:= if ({OEORDLIN_SQL.prod_cat} in ["TRD","TSI"]) then 1 else 0
isNotInPRODCAT:= if not({OEORDLIN_SQL.prod_cat} in ["TRD","TSI"]) then 1 else 0
```

Then insert two summary fields in your subreport's report footer section.  Make them the `max()` of the two functions.

Create 2 shared variables:

```
    shared numbervar max_isInPRODCAT:= {max_isInPRODCAT}        
    shared numbervar max_isNotInPRODCAT:= {max_isNotInPRODCAT}
```

then in the main report, check if max_isInPRODCAT = 1 and max_isNotInPRODCAT = 1

HTH

Comment: Did as you suggested but formulas are evaluated at the row level, same problem as before. Any other ideas?

Comment: you need to do your check in the main report on a section underneath the detail section where the shared variable is calculated.  Check the return values from the subreports in the main report to make sure they're being set and passed correctly.

Comment: Sub report is passing fine.  Problem is formula is running on each item on the report. So if there are 3 items I get three results.  I need the formula to run against all items as a whole and return one result.